Merge Data From Two Google Sheets (Where some rows do not have data in the other sheet)
How do I pull columns from Sheet2 into Sheet1 and line up the rows based on the Id in column A?
I don't want to use VLookup.
Sheet1 has 420 facilities.
Sheet2 has 220 of the 420 facilities.
What is the most efficient way to merge the columns from the two sheets taking into consideration that the destination sheet should have empty cells in rows that weren't in Sheet2?
VLookup from past experience populates empty rows with data from the last row it found.
I have tried variations of these:
=IFERROR(QUERY(Fac_ProfileQ!$A$2:$BT,"Select A Where A='" & A2 & "'"),0)
=filter(Fac_ProfileQ!A2:A,Merge!A2:A=$A1)
